# PyGTK + Glade: button without any signal triggers another signal

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

I'm developing a Python application using PyGTK+ 3.0 with Glade 3.22.2 (and Python 3.8.1). Everything was fine, but, suddenly, my program started to show a strange behavior. I have two methods to handle some buttons clicks: `on_save_file()` and `on_open_file()`. These functions take a `Gtk.Entry` as parameter and open/save a file and set the filename to the provided `Gtk.Entry`.

The strange part begins now: suddenly, a button that opens a file started to magically trigger a click on other two buttons in other windows that saves a file. The result is three FileDialogs showing up at the same time.

Just for testing, I removed the `on_open_file` signal of that button. And it continues to trigger the other two...

I also tried to get back some commits, but the error was still there (I'm almost sure that it didn't happened before in the same way that I'm almost sure I didn't update anything on my virtual environment).

Does anyone have any idea where this problem might be?

Thank you!

---

### More details

Here are my three methods (and signal handlers):

```py
# class blahblahblah: ...
def open_file(self, use_last_path=True) -> str:
    """
    Show an Open File dialog and return the filename

    :param use_last_path: Whether or not to start at the last folder opened
    :return: the selected filename
    """
    file_chooser = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(
        title="Open...", action=Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN)
    file_chooser.add_buttons(
        "Cancel", Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL, "Open", Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
    file_chooser.set_default_response(Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
    file_chooser.add_filter(self.csv_file_filter)
    if self.last_opened_path and use_last_path:
        file_chooser.set_current_folder(self.last_opened_path)
    response = file_chooser.run()
    filename = None
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        filename = file_chooser.get_filename()
        self.last_opened_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(filename))
    file_chooser.destroy()
    return filename

def on_save_file(self, entry: Gtk.Entry) -> None:
    """Show a Save File dialog and set the filename to the given entry"""

    file_chooser = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(
        title="Save...", action=Gtk.FileChooserAction.SAVE)
    file_chooser.add_buttons(
        "Cancel", Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL, "Save", Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
    file_chooser.set_default_response(Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
    file_chooser.add_filter(self.csv_file_filter)
    response = file_chooser.run()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        filename = file_chooser.get_filename()
        entry.set_text(filename)
    file_chooser.destroy()

def on_open_file(self, entry: Gtk.Entry) -> None:
    """Show an Open File dialog and set the filename to the given entry"""

    filename = self.open_file()
    if filename:
        entry.set_text(filename)
```

The button that should open a file (as I said, I removed the `on_open_file` signal).

```xml
<object class="GtkButton">
  <property name="label" translatable="yes">Open</property>
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="can_focus">True</property>
  <property name="receives_default">True</property>
</object>
```

The button that are triggered:

```xml
<object class="GtkButton">
  <property name="label" translatable="yes">Browse</property>
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="can_focus">True</property>
  <property name="receives_default">True</property>
  <signal name="clicked" handler="on_save_file" object="GA_output_matrix" swapped="no"/>
</object>

<object class="GtkButton">
  <property name="label" translatable="yes">Browse</property>
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="can_focus">True</property>
  <property name="receives_default">True</property>
  <signal name="clicked" handler="on_save_file" object="OPS_output_matrix" swapped="no"/>
</object>
```

Each button above are in a different file, and I load them using `Gtk.Builder`:

```py
builder: Gtk.Builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file('./Views/main.glade')
builder.add_from_file('./Views/ga.glade')
builder.add_from_file('./Views/ops.glade')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    builder.connect_signals(Handler())
    window = builder.get_object('main_window')
    window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but adding an ID for each button solved the bug. The buttons became:

```xml
<object class="GtkButton" id="a_semantic_id_1">
  <property name="label" translatable="yes">Open</property>
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="can_focus">True</property>
  <property name="receives_default">True</property>
</object>

<object class="GtkButton" id="a_semantic_id_2">
  <property name="label" translatable="yes">Browse</property>
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="can_focus">True</property>
  <property name="receives_default">True</property>
  <signal name="clicked" handler="on_save_file" object="GA_output_matrix" swapped="no"/>
</object>

<object class="GtkButton" id="a_semantic_id_3">
  <property name="label" translatable="yes">Browse</property>
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="can_focus">True</property>
  <property name="receives_default">True</property>
  <signal name="clicked" handler="on_save_file" object="OPS_output_matrix" swapped="no"/>
</object>
```